# How to print array data inside a table

Tags: javascript

So I have this code where I'm trying to print(physical print as in paper) a table when a button is clicked, which is populated with array data.
I managed to print the array data but I can not seem to find on how to put this in a table.
also is there a better way than `document.write()`I am not a huge fan of it ?

```
var Obj = [];

    function printDiv(){
        var divContents = document.getElementsByClassName("test")
        console.log(divContents) 
        //if($("div").hasClass("test") == true){// can use jquery hasfind in order to check if acive class exists if yes get content of child divs
            //expand if this option is better
        //console.log('istrue'); 
        //} 
        for(var i = 0; i< divContents.length; i++){
            Obj.push(divContents[i].textContent +'</br>')
        }
       
        var a = window.open('','','height=500,width=500');
        a.document.write('<html>');
        a.document.write('<body><h1>Div contents are<h1><br>');
        a.document.write('<table><tbody><tr>')
        a.document.write('<td>'+ Obj.join(' ')+'<td>');
        a.document.write('</tr></tbody></table></body></html>');
        a.document.close();
        a.print();
        Obj = [];
    }
```

expected outcome would be:
[image: outcome]

work order and date are not yet populated this is just a test file to use in a bigger project.

jsfiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/yLz7stxr/

thanks in advance.

Comment: Is your current code failing in some way?  From the text of the question it sounds like your current solution works and you're just looking for alternate solutions.

Comment: @david the code is partially working I can print the array data but I can not seem to fit it inside a table like the expected outcome. as for the alternate solution I was just asking it because I read `document.write()` is kinda outdated.

Comment: Create a stylesheet for printing only.

Comment: Could you please create a [small demo](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) for this using [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/) or [snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/358993/1823841) here.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/yLz7stxr/ jsfiddle that show what I got

Comment: where come from your work order and date data are?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here is the solution you just need to replace ${} in code link.

```
code: https://jsfiddle.net/vnxd1pew/3/
```

[image: Updated Image]

Comment: `<td style="border: 1px solid #ddd;
  padding: 8px;">${Obj[0]}</td>
    <td style="border: 1px solid #ddd;
  padding: 8px;">${Obj[1]}</td>
    <td style="border: 1px solid #ddd;
  padding: 8px;">${Obj[2]}</td>` is this a correct way to call my array data ? in this example

Answer (score 1):

I assume we got an array of objects here.

```js
const dataObject = {'name': null, 'age': null, 'favoriteFood': null};

let data = [];

let row = {...dataObject};
row.name = 'John';
row.age = '10';
row.favoriteFood = 'Pancakes';
data.push(row);

row = {...dataObject};
row.name = 'Jenny';
row.age = '11';
row.favoriteFood = 'Pie';
data.push(row);

row = {...dataObject};
row.name = 'James';
row.age = '12';
row.favoriteFood = 'Fries';
data.push(row);

// build table header
let tableHeaderColumns = Object.keys(data[0]).map(colKey => `<th>${colKey}</th>`).join('');
const tableHeader = `<tr align=left>${tableHeaderColumns}</tr>`;

// build table rows
let i = 0;
let tableRows = '';
let greyStyle = 'background-color: #EEE;';
data.forEach(function(rowObject) {
  const row = Object.values(rowObject).map(colValue => `<td>${colValue}</td>`).join('');
  let rowStyle = '';
  if(++i%2) {
    rowStyle = greyStyle;
  }
  
  tableRows += `<tr style='${rowStyle}'>${row}</tr>`;
});

// build table (add desired styling)
const table = `<table cellspacing=0 width=500 border=1 borderColor=#EEE style='border-collapse: collapse;'>${tableHeader}${tableRows}</table>`;

// for demonstration display in div
document.querySelector('div').innerHTML = table;
```

```html
<div />
```